# How to use multiple input features with associated extractors in a pipeline?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am working on a classification task with Scikit-learn. I have a data set in which each observation comprises two separate text fields. I want to set up a Pipeline in which each text field is passed in parallel through its own TfidfVectorizer and the outputs of the TfidfVectorizer objects are passed to a classifier. My aim is to be able to optimize the parameters of the two TfidfVectorizer objects along with those of the classifier, using GridSearchCV.

The Pipeline might be depicted as follows:

```
Text 1 -> TfidfVectorizer 1 --------|
                                    +---> Classifier
Text 2 -> TfidfVectorizer 2 --------|
```

I understand how to do this without using a Pipeline (by just creating to TfidfVectorizer objects and working from there), but how do I set this up inside a Pipeline?

Thanks for any help,

Rob.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Pipeline` and `FeatureUnion` classes. The code for your case would look something like:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
  ('features', FeatureUnion([
    ('c1', Pipeline([
      ('text1', ExtractText1()),
      ('tf_idf1', TfidfVectorizer())
    ])),
    ('c2', Pipeline([
      ('text2', ExtractText2()),
      ('tf_idf2', TfidfVectorizer())
    ]))
  ])),
  ('classifier', MultinomialNB())
])
```

You can do a grid search over the entire structure by referring to the parameters by using the `<estimator1>__<estimator2>__<parameter>` syntax. For example `features__c1__tf_idf1__min_df` refers to the `min_df` parameter of `TfidfVectorizer 1` from your diagram.

Comment: Thanks- so are ExtractText1 and ExtractText2 classes that inherit from TransformerMixin, or something simpler?

Comment: Actually, I think I've found the relevant example: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html#example-hetero-feature-union-py

Comment: Yes, the page you linked has a good example. In general you need some custom code to extract the portion of the data for each branch of the `FeatureUnion`.

Comment: @RobGoon
The link is broken.

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/0.18/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html ?